# Check if in an url is present a term - javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I have this code to analyze the traffic on a certain website:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener( function(details) {
    console.log(details);
},{
    urls: ["https://*.akamaihd.net/*"],
    types: ["xmlhttprequest"]
},["responseHeaders"]);
```

I need to check if in the urls returned by the `webRequest` api there is the `master.m3u8` term, if found I want to stop the process and use the url to do some code stuff. How I can accomplish this?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is because you're almost there: simply check `details.url`. However, in JavaScript you can't really "stop" the process so what exactly do you want to do? Will it be something synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: @wOxxOm I need to check if the `details.url` contains the `master.m3u8` word and if this condition match, I want to take the url to use it. I've read about the `includes()` javascript function but I'm not sure if will work as I expect and if this is the correct use case. For the process, I want to stop it if the url include the `master.m3u8` word, something synchronous will be fine.

Comment: I think you can specify the filter like `"https://*.akamaihd.net/*master.m3u8*"` and the listener will be triggered only for such URLs so you won't need any additional checks inside.

Comment: Thanks, I need to test. Any possibility to stop the network monitoring after the url is checked and match?

Comment: Use a named function and specify it in chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.removeListener, [example](https://gomakethings.com/named-vs-anonymous-event-listener-functions/).

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for the help.